# Locally Bounded Sequence of Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: U\to U$ be an analytic function with $0$ in $U$, where $U$ is an open connected subset of the complex plane. Let $f(0)=0$ and $|\frac{d}{dz}\,f(z)|=|f'(z)|<1$ for all $z$ in $U$. Define iteratively $f^{(n)}(z)$ as the composition of $f$ with itself $n$ times. Is this sequence $\{f^{(n)}(z)\}$ uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $U$?
I think that the assertion is true and was trying to prove it using $f$ is locally Lipschitz.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim that
$$\left|\frac{d}{dz}f^{(n)}(z)\right|<1,\qquad z\in U,n\geq 1.$$
The proof is by induction; the base case $n=1$ is given in the problem. For the inductive step, observe that
$$
\frac{d}{dz}f^{(n)}(z)=f'(f^{(n-1)}(z))\cdot \frac{d}{dz}f^{(n-1)}(z).
$$
Now observe that $$f^{(n-1)}(z)\in f^{(n-1)}(U)\subset f^{(n-2)}(U)\subset \cdots \subset U.$$
Hence it follows that
$$
\left|\frac{d}{dz}f^{(n)}(z)\right|< 1\cdot \left|\frac{d}{dz}f^{(n-1)}(z)\right|,
$$
completing the induction.

Combined with $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, this gives us a uniform bound on compact subsets of $U$.

Comment: Can you please explain how are you getting the uniform bound?

Comment: If you haven't gotten the bound by now, here is one approach. Fix a compact set $K\subset U$. Define a function $f\colon K\to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ by setting $g(z)$ to be the infimum of the length of all smooth paths in $U$ from 0 to $z$. It is not hard to see that $g$ is continuous and finite valued (since $U$ is path-connected). Hence $g$ is bounded, say $g\leq M$. Then it follows that $|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq M$ by writing $f^{(n)}$ as the integral of its antiderivative and applying the triangle inequality, giving you the uniform bound.